# Polars write_avro schema has empty name

Tags: python-polars

I need to upload AVRO file to BQ and get:

```
BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid name:
```

There is an empty string in invalid name error message. It is probably coming from here:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "bar": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    }
)
path = "new_file.avro"
df.write_avro(path)

open(path, "r+b").read()[:200]
```

And here is the output schema:

```
{"type":"record","name":"","fields":[
    {"name":"foo","type":["null","long"]},
    {"name":"bar","type":["null","long"]},
    {"name":"ham","type":["null","string"]}
    ]
 }
```

I suspect BQ complains about the empty name="". What are the workarounds here?

Comment: You may have to ask on https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues

Comment: @jqurious in issue type Question they suggest to use Stack. not 100% sure this is a bug or a feature. would you suggest to submit a bug on polars git?

Comment: The ask on stack is more for "how do I do X in polars?". This seems to be the first question ever asked about `.write_avro` (on stack or on github), and you have no responses - so I don't think it would be wrong to also post on the issues tracker.